# python dataframe melt with compound index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I have a dataframe like:

| index | sample_1 | sample_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A/1 | 23 | 33 |
| A/2 | 24 | 34 |
| A/3 | 25 | 35 |

I want to convert to:

| index | letter | number | value | sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 23 | sample_1 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 33 | sample_2 |
| 3 | A | 2 | 24 | sample_1 |
| 4 | A | 2 | 34 | sample_2 |
| 5 | A | 3 | 25 | sample_1 |
| 6 | A | 3 | 35 | sample_2 |

I have tried to use melt function, but the compounded index columns are loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `str.split` the column and then `df.melt`.

```
df[['letter','index']] = df['index'].str.split('/', expand=True)
res = (df.melt(id_vars=['letter','index'],var_name='sample')
       .sort_values(by='index')
       .rename(columns={ 'index' : 'number'})
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
print(res)

  letter number    sample  value
0      A      1  sample_1     23
1      A      1  sample_2     33
2      A      2  sample_1     24
3      A      2  sample_2     34
4      A      3  sample_1     25
5      A      3  sample_2     35
```

Answer (score 0):

using melt :

```
df = df.melt(value_vars=['sample_1','sample_2'], id_vars='index',var_name='sample')
df[['letter','number']] = df['index'].str.split('/',expand=True)
```

output:

```
>>>
  index    sample  value letter number
0   A/1  sample_1     23      A      1
1   A/2  sample_1     24      A      2
2   A/3  sample_1     25      A      3
3   A/1  sample_2     33      A      1
4   A/2  sample_2     34      A      2
5   A/3  sample_2     35      A      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pd.wide_to_long` then split and rename columns

```py
df_ = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["sample_"], i="index", j="sample").reset_index()
df_[['index', 'number']] = df_['index'].str.split('/', expand=True)
df_ = df_.rename(columns={'index': 'letter', 'sample_': 'value'})
df_ = df_.assign(sample='sample_' + df_['sample'].astype(str), index=df_.index+1)
```

```
print(df_)

  letter    sample  value number  index
0      A  sample_1     23      1      1
1      A  sample_1     24      2      2
2      A  sample_1     25      3      3
3      A  sample_2     33      1      4
4      A  sample_2     34      2      5
5      A  sample_2     35      3      6
```

For a more nested version, you can use

```py
df[['index', 'number']] = df['index'].str.split('/', expand=True)
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, ["sample_"], i=["index", 'number'], j="sample").reset_index()
      .rename(columns={'index': 'letter', 'sample_': 'value'})
      .pipe(lambda df: df.assign(sample='sample_' + df['sample'].astype(str), index=df.index+1))
      )
```